# Cannot send file from frontend to the server in a MERN project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multer

I have been trying to send an image file from the React frontend to the server but the file is not getting sent :

This is my front end code :

```
useEffect(()=>{
        const getImage=async ()=>{
            
            if(file){
              
              const data=new FormData();
              data.append("name",file.name);
              data.append("file",file);
              
              
              const response=await API.uploadFile(data);
             

              post.picture=response.data;

            }
        }
        getImage();
        
    },[file])
```

file is React state which contains the uploaded file

Here , on onClick event , I have updated the file state with the help of setFile function :

```
<label htmlFor="fileInput">
    <Add fontSize="large" color="action"/>
</label>
       
<input 
    type="file" 
    id="fileInput"
    style={{display:"none"}}
    onChange={(e)=>{
    setFile(e.target.files[0])
                
   }
  }
              
/>
```

This is my backend end point :

```
router.post("/file/upload",upload.single("file"),uploadImage);
```

I am using the multer middleware :

```
import multer from "multer";
import {GridFsStorage} from "multer-gridfs-storage";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const username=process.env.DB_USERNAME;
const password=process.env.DB_PASSWORD;


// we will store image/file with the help of multer-gridfs-storage's component 
  //GridFsStorage 

const storage=new GridFsStorage({
    // url of database where the file will be uploaded 
    url:`mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@cluster0.xki5wr4.mongodb.net/blog? 
    retryWrites=true&w=majority`,
    options:{useNewUrlParser:true},
    file:(request,file) => {
        // tyles of files that we will accept 
        const match=["image/png","image/jpg,image/jpeg"];
        
        
        if(match.indexOf(file.memeType)===-1){
            return `${Date.now()}-blog-${file.originalname}`;
        }
         
        // if the file extention matched 
        return {
            bucketName:"photos",
            filename:`${Date.now()}-blog-${file.originalname}`
        }
    }
})
export default multer({storage});
```

This is the callback function

```
const url="http://localhost:8000";

export const uploadImage=(request,response)=>{
   
    
    if(!request.file){
        return response.status(404).json({msg:"file not found"})
    }
    
    
    const imageUrl=`${url}/file/${request.file.filename}`;
    
    return response.status(200).json({imageUrl});

}
```

Since I am making API call through axios interceptors , I have updated the header
section as well
This is my header section :

```
headers:{
        "Accept": "application/json,form-data", 
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        // "Content-Type": "'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"
    }
```

Whenever I am trying to upload the file , it is throwing me error , file not found

request is getting sent and file name is going fine , only file is not getting sent

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several bugs. Fix these, maybe the problem will be solved:

replace:

```
if (match.indexOf(file.memeType) === -1) {
to
if (match.indexOf(file.mimetype) === -1) {
```

replace:

```
const match=["image/png","image/jpg,image/jpeg"];

to     
const match = ["image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"];
```

change status code:

```
if (!request.file) {
    return response.status(400).json({ msg: "File not received" });
}
```

replace headers to:

```
headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting 400 error not only while inserting an image but also while trying to login into my application

Comment: maybe for content-type, use "multipart/form-data" only to send file requests, for login and other, use "application/json"